# detect position in pattern and shift

Tags: python-3.x

Simply, I wish to achieve the following with for or while loops, when user input is 6.

```
z....z
.z..z.
..zz..
..zz..
.z..z.
z....z

zz....
..z..z
...zz.
...zz.
..z..z
zz....

.zz...
z..z..
....zz
....zz
z..z..
.zz...
```

Comment: Could you show what it would look like with more than 3? I don't see a concrete pattern in just these three. Are you looking for a binary `XOR`, `OR`, or something else?

Comment: sure, will update the question

Comment: Okay, I see it now. It's basically a bitwise right-shift that wraps around. I'll update my answer when I get some free time to mess with this.

Comment: Thank you. I do come across samples that i do not understand, so do kindly ease my understanding with for loops, with minimal while loops. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You should probably add your original code back to the question so readers can see that you gave it an honest shot before asking. I don't want to see your question get downvoted.

Comment: @sporkbox: Many thanks i understand your intentions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def create_pattern(pattern_size):
    # Create our list that'll be storing this info
    pattern = []

    # first_x and last_x are "memory" so we know where to place the Xes.
    first_x = 0
    last_x = pattern_size - 1

    # Next, create an inner list for each line
    for level in range(0, pattern_size):

        # start our new line
        pattern.append([])

        # Now place the Xes where they belong
        for x in range(0, pattern_size):
            if x == first_x or x == last_x:
                pattern[level].append("x")
            else:
                pattern[level].append(".")

        # Move the Xes to the new positions
        first_x += 1
        last_x -= 1
    return pattern

# see 'help(list.pop)' and 'help(list.insert)' for more details
def right_shift(line):
    buf = line.pop()
    line.insert(0, buf)
    return line

# This function just acts upon each line of a pattern
def shift_pattern(pattern):
    for line in range(0, len(pattern)):
        line = right_shift(pattern[line])
    return pattern

if __name__ == "__main__":
    original = create_pattern(7)
    for j in range(len(original)):
        if j != 0:
            original = shift_pattern(original)
        for i in range(len(original)):
            print("".join(original[i]))

        print()
```

This problem was pretty neat. What you needed was a right-shift. So what I did 
was break the pattern down into lines and characters using lists. There may be a 
more efficient way to do it, but it seemed like the most straightforward way to 
do it since Python strings are immutable and lists are mutable.

`create_pattern()` simply sets up our "input pattern", which gets manipulated 
after it's `print()`ed the first time.

The most interesting (and important) part to me is `right_shift()`. My first 
attempt was setting list indices procedurally. That method halfway worked, but 
is prone to error. I then remembered `pop()`. A quick `help(list)` revealed to 
me that I could simply pop the last element from the list and put it at the 
beginning to "fake" the right shift. The result?

```
x.....x
.x...x.
..x.x..
...x...
..x.x..
.x...x.
x.....x

xx.....
..x...x
...x.x.
....x..
...x.x.
..x...x
xx.....

.xx....
x..x...
....x.x
.....x.
....x.x
x..x...
.xx....

..xx...
.x..x..
x....x.
......x
x....x.
.x..x..
..xx...

...xx..
..x..x.
.x....x
x......
.x....x
..x..x.
...xx..

....xx.
...x..x
x.x....
.x.....
x.x....
...x..x
....xx.

.....xx
x...x..
.x.x...
..x....
.x.x...
x...x..
.....xx
```

This was a fun and interesting problem. Enjoy. :)

Note: Change the 7 in `create_pattern()` to another number to produce the other patterns.

Comment: I understand what you mean but actually what I would like is, for the 1st pattern i would print out: x....x (1st row) .x..x. (2nd row) & the second pattern xx.... (1st row) ..x..x (2nd row). Im missing much more than i thought?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean. Could you create a paste or edit your original post to better explain? Perhaps with 3-5 lines of each pattern so I or others may better understand the pattern?